# How can I add my BLT project changes to GIT

Tags: drupal-8

I am unable to commit my changes to GIT, I am getting below messages while committing my changes.

```
> tests:twig:lint:files
Linting twig files...
All Twig files contain valid syntax.
> tests:yaml:lint:files
Linting YAML files...
> tests:composer:validate
Validating composer.json and composer.lock...
[ExecStack] composer validate --no-check-all --ansi
[ExecStack] Running composer validate --no-check-all --ansi in 
/Users/784187/Projects/takeda/takeda-poc
./composer.json is valid
[ExecStack] Done in 0.796s
Your local code has passed git pre-commit validation.
Executing .git/hooks/commit-msg...
Validating commit message syntax...
[error]  Invalid commit message! 
Commit messages must conform to the regex /(^BLT-[0-9]+(: )[^ ].{15,}\.)|(Merge branch (.)+)/
The commit message should include your project prefix, followed by a hyphen and ticket number, followed by a colon and a space, fifteen characters or more describing the commit, and end with a period.
Example: BLT-123: Update module configuration.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to your BLT default configuration.

Go to the file `blt/blt.yml` and replace `prefix` value with your project code.

```
project:
  prefix: BLT
```

to

```
project:
  prefix: YOUR-PROJECT-CODE
```

If you set `prefix` value as `PRJ` then the commit message format will be

```
PRJ-[ticket number]: [message with minimum 15 letter]
```

**Example:** `PRJ-123: Added Initial source code with configuration.`